# boost.asio error codes on windows are platform-dependent?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am writing a small network client program, it uses boost.asio as
the network layer, this is a function used to cast error codes of
boost.asio to error codes of my program.

Today I found that if my client program starts while the server is
not opened, connect will fails, boost.asio's error code will not be
'asio::error::connection_refused' or 'system::errc::connection_refused'
but 'ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED', this is a windows platform-dependent
error code, to deal with this I added a macro to the code, but I think
this is just ugly.

```
inline ErrorCode::Code cast(const boost::system::error_code& ec, ErrorCode::Code d = ErrorCode::unknownError)
{
    if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
        return ErrorCode::operationCanceled;
    }
    if (ec == boost::system::errc::connection_refused || ec == boost::asio::error::connection_refused) {
        return ErrorCode::connectionRefused;
    }

    if (ec.category() == boost::system::get_system_category()) {
#if defined(BOOST_ASIO_WINDOWS)
        if (ec.value() == ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED) {
            return ErrorCode::connectionRefused;
        }
#endif
    }
    return d;
}
```

Is there other correct way to deal with this ?

---

I am confused, default_error_condition's value is still 1225,
on my computer, 'boost::system::errc::connection_refused' is 107,
and 'boost::asio::error::connection_refused' is 10061.

So where is the platform-independent error code ?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want to use using `error_condition` instead of `error_code` here.

> Class error_condition
>
> The class `error_condition` describes an object used to hold values identifying error conditions. [ Note: `error_condition` values are portable abstractions, while `error_code` values are implementation specific. --end note ]

Documentation suggests `error_code::default_error_condition` should work for you.

Also highly interesting is this page: http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/errorhandling.html

> This chapter introduces two Boost C++ Libraries assisting a developer in leveraging error handling: Boost.System translates operating system specific error codes into platform independent ones
>
> boost::system::error_condition is used just like boost::system::error_code. Both the value() and category() method can be called for the boost::system::error_condition object as shown in the above example.
>
> The reason for having two more or less identical classes is fairly simple: While `boost::system::error_code` is used for platform dependent error codes, `boost::system::error_condition` is used to access platform independent error codes instead. By calling the default_error_condition() method, a platform dependent error code is translated into a platform independent error code of type `boost::system::error_condition`.

Comment: Today I noticed this bug [appears to have been fixed in Boost 1.58](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html#boost_asio.history.asio_1_10_6___boost_1_58): [#10744](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10744)